# How to extract last objectID of mongoDB document in Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I want to extract last objectID of a document from a collection in python and want to store it in python object.

I am doing something like this

```
db.dataset2.find().sort( {'_id': -1 } ).limit(1);
```

But it gives me an error.

```
TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of the list
```

Please help.

Answer (score 5):

You are doing it wrong. The [`.sort`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.sort) takes a key or list and optional direction as arguments.

```
db.dataset2.find().sort('_id', pymongo.DESCENDING).limit(1)[0]['_id'];
```

or

```
db.dataset2.find().sort('_id', -1).limit(1)[0]['_id'];
```

Comment: Thanks, your second line of code worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor = mycol.find().sort('_id', -1).limit(1)
for document in cursor:
    print(document)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.